Are Hurdle models equivalent to zero inflated models?
In other words, can hurdle models be transformed to/from zero inflated models?
I was looking at the wikipedia page for hurdle models. As I understand the distinction, Hurdle models are just a probability of zero, and a strictly non zero distribution for the non zero case.
Zero inflated models models are a probability for zero, and a distribution which includes zero for the other case.
So you can take a zero inflated model, factor out the probability of zero to a single case, and call it a hurdle model, right? Am I missing something?
They both seem capable of forming the same total probability distribution.

You are correct: Both models are capable of forming the same probability distributions and they are just parameterized differently.
However, as you link these different parameters to regressors, the resulting regression models are typically not equivalent. There are certain special cases where also the regression models yield the same fitted distributions, e.g., when the same saturated model is used for both the zero part and the count part of the models. But beyond these rather specific cases the models are not the same. Thus, the interpretation of the coefficients and the corresponding effect displays, marginal effects, etc. differ as well.
How different the models are depends on what the probability for zero is in the count component. If this is small (i.e., if positive counts and zeros are well-separated), the differences between hurdle and zero-inflation model are typically small as well. Otherwise, the differences are more pronounced, especially regarding the interpretation of the probability for "zero" vs. "excess zero".
